# Unable to run Junit case case .Throws error "Actually there were zero interactions with this mock"

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-junit

I am trying to unit test a class. The class is as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyConfig.class)
Class MyTest{

 @Mock
 pirvate JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;


  @InjectMocks
  private final ProductService productService= new ProductService();

  @Test
      public void sendItem(){
             Item i = new Item();
             i.name("xyz");
            productService.send(i)
            verfity(jmsTemplate).convertAndSend("product.test",i)
      }
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource(classpath:application-test.properties)
class MyConfig{

  @Bean
  ProductService productService(){
    return new ProductService();
  }

  @Bean
  JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
     return new JmsTemplate();
  }
}

resources folder under test package has

application.properties, contents of it are

spring.profiles.active=test

And application-test.properties has
queue.name=product.test
```

My productService class is as follows

```
class ProductService{
  @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

   @Value("${queue.name}")
    private String queue;

    public void send(Item i){
         jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue,i)
    }
}
```

When i run the above test case i get,

I getting mockito wanted but not invoked,
    Actually there were zero interactions with this mock.
    But Argument passed to convertAndSend method match
can anyone suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your beans you injected into the test do not seem to be Spring managed. What about this?

```
@MockBean
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;
```